# Swinging of a bob

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work

[image]

Suppose a variable force is acting on the bob and making it swing as shown in the figure then why will kinetic energy be conserved here even though there is a variable force acting on the bob?

Comment: What variable force are you talking about? Gravity is assumed to be constant in most pendulum analyses. The tension varies but does no work. Kinetic energy isn't constant, and there is no general principle for conservation of kinetic energy. What are you asking about?

Comment: @BillN It's an external force

Comment: There's no external force shown in the figure.

Comment: @BillN Can you help now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straight-forward application of the mechanical work-energy theorem: the net work done by all forces acting on a body as it moves from position $i$ to position $f$ is equal to the change in the kinetic energy of the body, $\Delta K = K_f-K_i$ or 
$$\sum_{\mathrm{all~forces}}W = \Delta K.$$
It doesn't matter what the nature and origins of the forces are. All that matters is whether they do work on the object (mechanically) or not. They may be conservative or non-conservative, time-dependent or constant.

Kinetic energy is not conserved, and the calculation of kinetic energy is frame-dependent, so this principle/theorem must be applied wisely.

The work energy theorem arises out of the conservation of energy when dealing with mechanical processes (and may carefully be extended to other processes, but we won't deal with that here): $$E_f=E_i+W_{\mathrm{non-conservative}}$$
where $E=K+U$, and $U$ is the system potential energy associated with some conservative force. As part of accounting for energy changes in a system, we either count the change in a potential energy **or** the work done by that conservative force, but not both. We also define changes in potential energy as $$\Delta U_n = -W_n,$$ where the $n$ subscript identifies a particular conservative force.

Replacing the $E_f$ and $E_i$ by $K+U$ we get the following:
$$K_f + \sum_n U_{nf}= K_i + \sum_n U_{ni} +W_{\mathrm{non-conservative}}$$
$$K_f - K_i = \sum_n\left(-U_{nf}+U_{ni} \right)+W_{\mathrm{non-conservative}}$$
$$K_f - K_i = \sum_n(W_n)+W_{\mathrm{non-conservative}}$$
$$\Delta K = W_{\mathrm{all}}$$

If the kinetic energies at two locations along a path are the same, then $\Delta K=0$ and the net work done by all external forces acting on the object while traveling between those two points will also be zero (not including thermodynamic effects). The variety of changes to velocities and speeds between those two points are irrelevant.

Comment: Since change in kinetic enrgy is zero in this case even though a variable force is acting on the bob which will surely change it's velocity at each turn

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla The work-energy principle doesn't tell us how the velocity or the speed has varied while travelling. All it tells us is a kinetic energy change between two points versus the work done while moving between two points. You get to choose the two points. A wise choice makes calculations easier.

Comment: @BillN I also have the same doubt sir.......shouln't the variable force just increase velocity hence the difference between the kinetic energies between any two points in this diagram will be positive instead of zero?Am I wrong to think that?

Comment: @harambe What two points are you choosing? If you choose the release point as initial and bottom of swing as final, then the kinetic energy increases. If you choose the bottom as an initial point and some angle $\theta \ne 0$ as final, then kinetic energy decreases. You get to choose the initial and final points, then apply the principle. Sometimes $\Delta K >0$, sometimes $\Delta K < 0$, sometimes, $\Delta K = 0$.

Comment: @BillN If I take bottom as initial and some $\theta\ne 0 $  then why will kinetic energy decrease as you stated above/

Comment: @harambe Think about it: gravity is acting downward, and the pendulum bob is moving upward. The speed will get smaller, so the kinetic energy decreases.

Comment: Okay I get that but what about the acceleration provided by variable force....won't that play a role here?

Comment: @harambe That is all wrapped up in the physics concept of work.

Comment: I am afraid I am not able to follow up the cause for neglecting it...can you please elaborate that for me sir

Comment: @harambe that's exactly my doubt too.....all i  can guess is that it has something to do with circular motion ..idk

Comment: Dynamics is one valid approach. Conservation of energy is another valid approach. One doesn't have to use both. When solving physics problems, part of the skill is learning what approaches are most fruitful. @HydrousCaperilla asked about conservation of energy, not acceleration.  If you want to know about acceleration in a pendulum, that's a different question and I won't address it in comments here.