# How will the $\mathbf F$ affect the velocity

Tags: forces, velocity

[image]

I know a similiar question has been asked but the respondent said it was a different concept and he won't address it so I posted it here...it's somewhat different from that though.Can you tell me whether this variable Force $\mathbf F$ affect the velocity of the bob.Will velocity increase,decrease or remain constant even though this example assumes it to be constant

Comment: Could you please show how you have tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: @harambe the example doesn’t assume a constant force, it just uses energy considerations to dispense with any explicit force analysis at all. The former method is preferred as the net force acting on the bob is a function of the angle theta so the force is variable along the trajectory and as such an integration is needed to get the work.

Comment: @CAF So the fact  that $\Delta$KE will be zero is wrong according to the concept so we have to find the function of velocity  to use work energy here?

Comment: @CAF also can you post your thoughts as an anwer as it will probably help me

Comment: @harambe Sure I’ll post an answer later on when I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this page only, it is not clear what the book is describing. I think the book is asking: what is the work done when lifting the bob from rest, **without** adding kinetic enegy (from rest to rest). The book clarifies that a simple way for finding the work done by the force, in this case, is by comparing with the work done by gravity *(mgh)* and string *(zero)*. This calculation is indifferent to the fact that the force may be variable.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/379768/swinging-of-a-bob/379932#comment851352_379932

Comment: can you just tell me why will velocity be same at those two points even though the variable force is accelerating thr bob?Gravity is slowing down the bob but the force will be accelerating it,won't it?

Comment: You can find several posts explaining this. Basically, the force may be accelerating the bob at some time interval and then slowing it down again. Imagine yourself lifting the bob. You can surely do it without adding any velocity at the end-point.

Comment: is this case like that of lifting the bob as yous tated

Answer (score 0):

Initially when the bob hasn't been released, F would be mg*Tan(theta).

I think that's not the right question to ask (whether or not F would change v).

For the bob to be initially held at a particular (theta), there would be a unique F, which would be mg*Tan(theta).

And so, the speed at the lowest point, which would be the max (Vmax), would vary based on the initial (theta).

Vmax = Sqrt(2gl(1-cos(theta)).

So rough answer is "the initial 'F' is dependent on theta, so is the 'Vmax'".